# Why can't a Higher Order Component (HOC) directly return it's component argument?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-functional-component, higher-order-components

I'm learning about Higher Order Components in React and I encountered some code that is very confusing to me.

```
function HOCFunction(Component){
    function handleComponent(){
        return (<Component/>);
    }
    return handleComponent;
}
```

^^^ This code will work and run normally. The HOC function takes a Component as a parameter, creates a functional component, and then returns it.

So here is my question...

```
function HOCFunction(Component){
    return (<Component/>)
}
```

^^^ This code throws an error "Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid..." I would expect this code to work as well. Why can't I directly return the component passed in as it's argument?
Is there something about JSX that I don't understand?

---

Edit - Here's how I'm using the HOC.. I'm using react native btw

```
const TextComponent = HOCFunction(() => {
    return <Text>this is text from a hoc</Text>
}
```

And then 'TextComponent' could be rendered like so..

```
function ParentComponent(){
    return( <TextComponent/> )
}
```

---

I would have expected to be able to return the component parameter directly, but in order for the code to run, it seems like I have to create a separate component inside the HOC function. Why is that?

Comment: You should show how you use it

Comment: In the first case, you define and return a function which, when run, returns some JSX. In the second case, you return that JSX directly. Why are you expecting the two to be the same? Or interchangeable, for that matter. Do you think `x` and `() => x` are interchangeable? If you replaced `return (<Component/>)` with `return () => (<Component/>)` they would be interchangeable.